# Pronunciation of 出入り

Tags: pronunciation, readings

In the context of people entering and leaving a room how is 出入り(する) pronounced? Is it でいり, ではいり or しゅつにゅう?  In what situations would the other readings be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

でいり refers to the abstract activity of people visiting the place often, whereas ではいり would refer to the physical act of going in and coming out.

E.g. you can say 人のでいりを記帳する but it would be odd to say 人のではいりを記帳する。Conversely, 段差をなくしではいりを楽にしましたmakes sense, whereas 段差をなくしでいりを楽にしました is not wrong but is a bit odd because it suggests this improvement made it easier for people to frequent the place.

しゅつにゅう is rare and the only example I can think of is 出入国。I’d guess it was created by concatenation 出国 and 入国rather than 出入 and 国 though I’m not sure.